# Using a hyperlink to submit a form instead of a button through an intermedite function is not working

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I want to submit a form through an 'edit(param1,param2)' function which in turn is being called in either of the two ways..

```
echo '<input type="button" value="DELETE" onclick="edit(\''.$key.'\',\''.$b.'\')"/>';
```

or

```
echo '<a href="list_cadmin.php" onclick="edit(\''.$key.'\',\''.$b.'\')"><span  class="bluetext">DEACTIVATE</span>';
```

the function edit() is something like this:

```
function edit(a,b) {
var answer = confirm("Do You Really want to Deactivate ?")
if (answer){
    alert(a)
document.getElementById('cid').value= a;
document.getElementById('key').value= b;
document.getElementById('fname').method='get';
document.getElementById('fname').action='samepage.php';
document.getElementById('fname').submit();
}
}
```

where $key and $b  are number and string values respectively.

so, according to the above both should go to 'samepage.php?cid=BLAHBLAH&key=1234' on onClick. But only the input=button is working. Hyperlink is reloading without the GET parameters. How do i get the hyperlink to work?

Comment: Is `fname` your form ID or name?

Comment: @MrCode both. I set both id and name of the form to 'fname'

Comment: you need post the form html code you have done or else we would be able to give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the `href` from executing by returning false from the `onclick`:

```
echo '<a href="list_cadmin.php" onclick="edit(\''.$key.'\',\''.$b.'\'); return false;"><span  class="bluetext">DEACTIVATE</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="edit(\''.$key.'\',\''.$b.'\')"><span  class="bluetext">DEACTIVATE</span></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo <<<EOD
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="edit('{$key}','{$b}')">
<span class="bluetext">DEACTIVATE</span></a>
EOD;
```